# Is this sentence an absolute construction or something else?

Tags: sentence-construction

I saw this sentence in the OED.

> His speech is immature, his vocabulary limited.

Obviously, the last section is not a clause. Is it an absolute construction or something else?
If we rephrase this section into an independent clause, it will be no problem.

His speech is immature, and his vocabulary is limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case of **gapping,** where one or more words included in one conjunct are omitted from later ones. Often, when this occurs, the conjunction is lost also; if we add the conjunction and the missing word back in, we get just what you suggested:

> His speech is immature, **and** his vocabulary **is** limited.